# Not receiving any messages from my telegram bot

Tags: configuration, telegram, telegram-bot

One of my telegram bots is not receiving any messages from anywhere/anybody/any-method.

Is there any way to config telegram bot not to receive anything? I might have done that to my that specific telegram bot long ago, as all the rest of my telegram bots are just fine.

Basically, to confirm that, I loop-call

https://api.telegram.org/botmybot_token/getUpdates

But I always get `{"ok":true,"result":[]}` for my that specific telegram bot, even when I'm sending numerous messages to it meanwhile, whereas all the rest of my telegram bots return normal update json just fine.

**UPDATE:**

So I just created two brand new bots, and for one I always get `{"ok":true,"result":[]}` while the other is fine. ***Strange***.